# If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import

Tags: django

'C:\Users\huihuiqian\mys ite\posts\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

mysite.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^posts/', include('posts.urls')),
]
```

post.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpartterns =[
    url(r'^$',views.index, name='index')
];
```

Comment: There is a typo in post.urls.py: 'urlpartterns' instead of 'urlpatterns'